# hasOne relationship in Laravel not working?

Tags: php, laravel-4, eloquent

I have a one to one relationship I am trying to get to work in *laravel*.

I have a `user` and an `alert` table I am trying to use.

Primarykey of `User` table is `id` and another id in there is called `id_custom`.

In the `Alerts` table I have `id_custom` as the **primary key**.

Here is the relationship in the users model:

```
   public function alerts()
   {
       return $this->hasOne('Alerts', 'id_custom');
   }
```

Here is the alerts model:

alerts->profit` (where `profit` is a column in the `Alerts` table.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried `return $this->hasOne(Alerts', 'id_custom', 'id')`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your `hasOne` method is currently looking for `user_id` in your `alerts` table. You need to explicitly set the foreign and local key you're looking for.

```
return $this->hasOne('Model', 'foreign_key', 'local_key');
```

[Source](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent)

In your instance if would be

```
return $this->hasOne('Alerts', 'id_custom', 'id');
```

You would make things much tidier for yourself if you changed the `User` attribute `id_custom` to `alert_id`.

Then you could change the method in your User.php model to `alert` and do:

```
public function alert()
{
    return $this->hasOne('Alerts');
}
```